# Is it possible to create a Mini ERP solution (Organisation specific) in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am a ASP.net Web Form Developer , I simply want to know that is it possible to develop a mini ERP solution in ASP.net MVC ?

I have already developed such in ASP.net Web Forms but our company wants to re-write to whole app from scratch for bigger scale with increased modules and functionalities.

So can we go with ASP.net MVC this time rather than Web Forms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325182/ideas-for-opensource-cms-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Everything you could do in WebForms could be done with MVC. After all ASP.NET MVC is based on the ASP.NET engine.